# How to pass Map<String, Any> as parameter using Retrofit2?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

I need to pass `Map<String, Any>` as parameter for PUT request. Json (made from Map) looks like this:

```
{
  "user": {
    "lastname": "Smith",
    "name": "John",
    ...
  },
  "foreign_language_keys": [
    "eng",
    "fr"
  ],
  "tachograph_cards": [
    {
      "tachograph_key": "estr",
      "tachograph_card_num":
      .....
```

If I pass `Map<String, String>` as parameter - it works fine:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
@PUT("api/authorization/user/driver/{user_id}")
fun editUser(@Path("user_id") userId: String, @FieldMap body: Map<String, String>): Single<UserModel>
```

But if I need to pass `Map<String, Any>` as parameter - I get runtime error "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter type must not include a type variable or wildcard: java.util.Map (parameter #2)"

Adding @JvmSuppressWildcards annotation (`@FieldMap body: Map<String, @JvmSuppressWildcards Any>)`) does not help (I get another error "Undefined index" from server for one of necessary fields in Json, because server does not see this field in my request).

The working solution is to make com.google.gson.JsonObject by mapping all fields from my model (instead of passing `Map<String, Any>`), but it is too difficult. I am sure it must work without converting my model to Json, but I could not find the easy solution.
Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON structure looks weird and inconsistent. You pass structure for Retrofit you need to define clear consistent structure. In your case, it looks like your map key is always String but the value part of map is sometimes Json object and sometimes an array/list or whatever. Not consistent which makes it impossible to exact structured value.

You can't surely post/put `Map<String, Any` because ? is illegal argument.

You can structure and send `Map<String, JsonObject>`, creation of JsonObject is not hard if you use Gson library. All you do is to extract the string (value part of the Json object) and give it to Gson library and then it generates the JsonObject model for you to pass.

Or you may send `Map<String, String>`, from parsing side, you `parse()` and `stringify(`) of Json value,

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same problem recently, and I found probably the easiest solution.
You can check my full answer to the similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61324340/7110268

In your particular case you can try this:

```
val body = mutableMapOf<String, String>()

body["user[lastname]"] = "Smith"
body["user[name]"] = "John"

body["foreign_language_keys[0]"] = "eng"
body["foreign_language_keys[1]"] = "fr"

// and so on
```

If you need to pass a huge dynamic list, you can easily fill your map in a `for` loop, for example.

Answer (score -1):

it has to be a mutable variable as a delegate property. to be able to punish the property you want to place with the Any

Your solution is to put MutableMap

```
interface MutableMap<K, V> 
    
V the type of map values. The mutable map is invariant in its value type.

interfaceMap<K, V> 
    
V the type of map values. The map is covariant in its value type.


@FormUrlEncoded
@Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
@PUT("api/authorization/user/driver/{user_id}")
fun editUser(@Path("user_id") userId: String, @FieldMap body: MutableMap<String, String>): Single<UserModel>
```

Comment: This is not a proper answer, please elaborate on how it can resolve the OP's problem.