# Send complex object using Retrofit2

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2

I'm trying to send a complex object as a parameter of my request using Retrofit2 and Kotlin.
Structure of that object is the following:

```
{
  "id": "..."
  "token": "..."
  "message": "..."
  "list1": [
    { "id": 1, "value": 2 },
    { "id": 2, "value": 5 }
    //and so on...
  ]
  "list2": [
    { "id": 10, "value": 16 },
    { "id": 11, "value": 21 }
    //and so on...
  ]
  //and so on...
}
```

The number of list fields is **various**(could be 2 lists, could be 10) as well as the number of items inside each list.
I'm using the following code to achieve that, previously filled my Map with the appropriate values:

```
@JvmSuppressWildcards
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("get_data.php")
fun getResponse(
    @FieldMap params: Map<String, Any>
): Observable<ResponseModelResult>
```

For some reason that approach is not working properly and the server just ignoring my params.
I've also tried to send them as `@Body` string/object, but it seems like the server **accepts only FormUrlEncoded data**.

Can someone give me an example how I should send such data as parameter using the `@FieldMap` approach?

Comment: You should create Json object first and then You can pass this object as string with @Field. For that you will require any key to pass this object.

Comment: @MaradiyaKrupa sorry, can't get the point. What do you mean by "will require any key to pass this object"?

Comment: If the server accepts only FormUrlEncoded, your code should work fine. @FieldMap(encoded = true) this is the only change you can make.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found a solution. Seems like retrofit can't deal with the `<String, Any>` map, so the easiest way would be to send request parameters in a similar way as, for example, in Postman.

```
val params = mutableMapOf<String, String>()
params["id"] = ...
params["token"] = ...
params["message"] = ...

params["list1[0][id]"] = "${1}"
params["list1[0][value]"] = "${2}"
params["list1[1][id]"] = "${2}"
params["list1[1][value]"] = "${5}"

params["list2[0][id]"] = "${10}"
params["list2[0][value]"] = "${16}"

//and so on
```

Then, in my ApiService:

```
@Headers("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("get_data.php")
fun getResponse(
    @FieldMap params: Map<String, String>
): Observable<ResponseModelResult>
```

Probably, that's not the best approach overall, but at least it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

YIf you provide demo url of your api or documentation or something else that would help me find out the problem more specific then I will update my answer according to your api mechanism, now you can try this:

Declare your api interface like this:

```
    @POST("get_data.php") 
    fun getResponse(@Query("params") params: String): Observable<ResponseModelResult>
```

Make your complex object like this:

```
    val jsonObject1 = JsonObject().apply {
        addProperty("id", 1)
        addProperty("value", 1)
    }

    val jsonObject2 = JsonObject().apply {
        addProperty("id", 2)
        addProperty("value", 2)
    }

    val list1 = JsonArray().apply {
        add(jsonObject1)
        add(jsonObject2)
    }

    val jsonObject10 = JsonObject().apply {
        addProperty("id", 10)
        addProperty("value", 16)
    }

    val jsonObject11 = JsonObject().apply {
        addProperty("id", 11)
        addProperty("value", 21)
    }

    val list2 = JsonArray().apply {
        add(jsonObject10)
        add(jsonObject11)
    }

    val params = JsonObject().apply {
        addProperty("id", "...")
        addProperty("token", "...")
        addProperty("message", "...")
        add("list1", list1)
        add("list2", list2)
    }.toString()
```

Here you are ready to go now, call your api passing `params` as query parameter like: `getResponse(params)`

Comment: Thanks for your response. There are 2 issues with the code you provided: 1. I can't have both FormUrlEncoded and Query in the same request (FormUrlEncoded is necessary in my case). 2. If I understood you approach correct, top-level param's key called "params", and all other objects (params) are nested. But the server can't parse "params" key anyway, I need to send id, token, message ect directly

Answer (score 0):

instead of **@FieldMap** you can use **@Field** like below.

@JvmSuppressWildcards
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("get_data.php")
fun getResponse(
    @Field(**"your key"**) jsonObject: String
): Observable

Pass the json object as string.

Comment: Got it now. But the problem is that the number of lists could change dynamically. E.g. user can select 1, 2, or even 10 lists, so in my case it's not a good idea to send each field separately as you suggested.